# creating javascript arrays in typescript when to use an interface, when not to, and when to use a constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

here is my understanding regarding java script object arrays in typescript

In my current code I am grabbing an array of json from an observable. As I understand it I can declare the array then initalize it without a need for a interface or type.

```
let cityList[]; // the value of cityList here is null correct?
cityList[] = response;
```

I could also use an interface too but it isn't necessary ever just a good idea so the compiler is your friend like in java no?

```
interface Blah{
city: string;
}

let cityList: Blah[];
cityList[] = response;
```

I as well could create a constructor (if I needed to dynamically add javascript objects to the array and thats the only time I would need to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was wrong I now KNow that this is the proper way of doing things.

I only need to create a constructor if I am adding an object or creating an new object that will be used in my code or sent over the wire.

I don't use interfaces, I use models

so if I wanted to create a city javascript object which just contains the cities name I would have the following

**this is written in typescript**

```
export class City{
  public name: string;

  constructor(name:string){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

then the array  i want to store these objects would have to have the proper type :

```
cityList:City[];
```

the array above in uninitialized to initalize it, set a value to the array or if you have no values but need it initalized set it to an empty array like so.

```
cityList: City[] = [];
```